# Get newly inserted document BSONObjectID

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo

i need to return newly inserted object. I read that i can generate my own id but that's not probably the case.

```
def create(repo: String) = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit req =>
    val id = BSONObjectID.generate
    collection(repo).insert($("_id " -> id)).map { last =>
      if(last.ok)
        Ok(Json.toJson($("_id"->id)++$("success"->true)))
      else
        BadRequest($("success"->false))
    }
}
```

And i'm generating records like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "556dfb2021c76e3b1c566915"
    },
    "_id ": {
        "$oid": "556dfb1f5f00006100d4a0bc"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not generate MongoDB `_id` manually unless you know for sure that they are unique or you will have to deal with `duplicated key exception` in your code.

If you insert a new document without `_id`, MongoDB will generate one for you during the insert process. Then if you want this `_id` back, you can request MongoDB to get back your document with your newly created `_id`.

Normally the drivers handle this part automatically for you.

Comment: You say "**Then if you want this _id back, you can request MongoDB to get back your document with your newly created _id**" but how exactly do you do this? The whole point is that you won't know the `_id` to make such a query

Answer (score 0):

Just missclick, i added space by mistake to _id, and that was causing all the problems